# Why the directory appears again after i removed in ubuntu14.04

Tags: linux, shell

`iotserver` is a directory which i was `git clone` from somewhere.Now,i want to remove it from my computer.But something strange happened.When i exec `rm -rf iotserver`,then exec `ls`,i can see it was removed.However,when i do something in another directory and get into the directory where the iotserver is ,**it appears again**! That make me confused.What's wrong?

The following is what i do:

```
john@ ~/Code/gitlab $ ls 
fpp_java  fppv2_pcserver  fppv2_phpserver  iotserver  streetlamp-server
john@ ~/Code/gitlab $ rm -rf iotserver/
john@ ~/Code/gitlab $ ls
fpp_java  fppv2_pcserver  fppv2_phpserver  streetlamp-server
john@ ~/Code/gitlab $ cd ..
john@ ~/Code $ ls
Ruby  android-formatting.xml  android.importorder  gitlab  mysql-connector-java-5.0.8
john@ ~/Code $ cd gitlab/
john@ ~/Code/gitlab $ ls
fpp_java  fppv2_pcserver  fppv2_phpserver  iotserver  streetlamp-server
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved when I restart the terminal, I think the reason may be it was opened in eclipse when I tried to remove it in the terminal.